# How to show list data in vertical list

Tags: web-part, xml

I want to show the contents of three specific columns from one specific list item.

Like Meeting list item ID 5  contains

```
Name           MeetingDate           Bitfield1            Bitfield2
John Doe       23-06-2010            Yes                  No
```

In a web part (if possible) I want to create this view:

```
Meeting Date: 23-06-2010
Bitfield1:    Yes
Bitfield2:    No
(Edit link to Meeting list item ID 5)
```

Is that possible without coding a web part from scratch? E.g. with the XML web part or others? (solution is MOSS 2007 Enterprise based if that's relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure that display using a DataView Web Part and structure the output in whatever format you need.

Comment: This seems to be the fastest solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, SharePoint has "Newsletter" Layouts which can present data in this way.

Otherwise, you can also create this with SharePoint Designer 2007 without using any code whatsoever.

Comment: Seems like the labels gets some weird locations (newsletter in my version is a horizontal layout). Box/Boxed seemed ok but the first label was missing.... seems like I'll have to go with the DataView Webpart solution...